# How to convert frozen graph to TensorFlow lite

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have been trying to follow,
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/object_detection/overview#model_customization
all day to convert any of the tensorflow Zoo models to a **TensorFlow Lite** model for running on Android with no luck.

I downloaded several of the models from here,
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md
(FYI, Chrome does not let you down these links as not https, I had to right-click Inspect the link and click on the link in the inspector)

I have the script,

```
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
    graph_def_file='frozen_graph.pb',
    input_shapes = {'normalized_input_image_tensor':[1,300,300,3]},
    input_arrays = ['normalized_input_image_tensor'],
    output_arrays = ['TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1', 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3']
)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

but gives the error,
ValueError: Invalid tensors 'normalized_input_image_tensor' were found

so the lines,

> input_shapes = {'normalized_input_image_tensor':[1,300,300,3]},
> input_arrays = ['normalized_input_image_tensor'],
> output_arrays = ['TFLite_Detection_PostProcess','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:1',
> 'TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:2','TFLite_Detection_PostProcess:3']

must be wrong, need a different shape, but how do I get this for each of the zoo models,
or is there some preconvert code I need to run first?

> Running the "code snipet" below I get,

```
--------------------------------------------------
Frozen model layers:
name: "add/y"
op: "Const"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_FLOAT
  }
}
attr {
  key: "value"
  value {
    tensor {
      dtype: DT_FLOAT
      tensor_shape {
      }
      float_val: 1.0
    }
  }
}

Input layer:  add/y
Output layer:  Postprocessor/BatchMultiClassNonMaxSuppression/map/while/NextIteration_1
--------------------------------------------------
```

But I don't see how this would map to the input_shape or help with the conversion??

Is it even possible to convert models like faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco to `tflite`? I read somewhere that only SSD models are supported?

So I tried to convert the faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco to tflite using the below suggested code, the conversation code did not work in TF1, but did work in TF2, but when I try to use the tflite file in the TFlite Example app I get this error,

```
2021-12-14 13:23:01.979 24542-24542/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/tflite: Missing 'operators' section in subgraph.
2021-12-14 13:23:01.984 24542-24542/org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection E/TaskJniUtils: Error getting native address of native library: task_vision_jni
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred when initializing ObjectDetector: Could not build model from the provided pre-loaded flatbuffer: Missing 'operators' section in subgraph.
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector.initJniWithByteBuffer(Native Method)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector.access$100(ObjectDetector.java:88)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector$3.createHandle(ObjectDetector.java:223)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.core.TaskJniUtils.createHandleFromLibrary(TaskJniUtils.java:91)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.task.vision.detector.ObjectDetector.createFromBufferAndOptions(ObjectDetector.java:219)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.<init>(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:88)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.tflite.TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.create(TFLiteObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:82)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.DetectorActivity.onPreviewSizeChosen(DetectorActivity.java:99)
        at org.tensorflow.lite.examples.detection.CameraActivity$7.onPreviewSizeChosen(CameraActivity.java:446)
```

Comment: Are you sure your input tensor name is correct? At least one of the models input tensor was named `image_tensor`.

Comment: no, they are not correct, how do I find the correct names? for each of the zoo models

Comment: You can, for example, use Netron (https://github.com/lutzroeder/netron) to visualize the protobuffs. Find the input and output tensors, and you can see their names.

Comment: is there simple python code to get the input_shape, input_array, output_array, or are these documented somewhere for the zoo models?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using tensorflow 1?

Comment: need to get it working for both tf1 and tf2, will do tf2 next, I assume will have a similar issue

Comment: Hi James. One quick question so I can help you. At the link you have provided with zoo models there is a category for MOBILE models that all contain .tflite files. These files are 6 to 12MB each and they are easy to integrate inside android phone. If you try to use a pretrained model from other category like the general files you will end up with 100MB tflite file. Is this something you want? Is there a specific model that you want to convert? Write the name here and I will get back to you.

Comment: We want to convert our own model retrained from some of these. Such as "ssd_resnet_50_fpn_coco" or "ssd_mobilenet_v1_fpn_coco", "ssd_inception_v2_coco", "faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco", which ever has the best accuracy, size is not an issue

Comment: is it even possible to convert models like faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco to tflite? I read somewhere that only ssd models are supported?

Comment: Are you working locally or on Colab/Google cloud?

Comment: working local (windows/python)

Comment: You can give it a try with my method below for faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco.....if you have the specific files and the model is of TF version 1 it will be OK. For TensorFlow 2 models things are much easier.

Comment: Oh, I forgot that you can also see the layer input names that you were looking for. image_tensor, detection_boxes, detection_classes, detection_scores, num_detections

Comment: I have also tested it with faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/saved_model and it produces the tflite file correctly

Comment: Hey James. Since I worked a lot of hours during Friday and Saturday for this, can you please  provide some feedback on my answer below? Did it help you to solve the problem? Is it eligible for correct answer and bounty? Thank you.

Comment: The code did not work with TF1

Comment: The code did work with TF2, but the tflite file does not work with Android

Answer (score 2):

Those models were made using TensorFlow version 1. so you have to use the saved_model to generate a concrete function (because TFLite doesn't like dynamic input shapes), and from there convert to TFLite.

I will write down a simple solution that you can use immediately.

Open a colab notebook, it is free and online. Go to [this address](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/)
and click on New Notebook at right down.

First cell (input below and execute with play button):

```
!wget http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/ssd_mobilenet_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync_2018_07_03.tar.gz
!tar -xzvf "/content/ssd_mobilenet_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync_2018_07_03.tar.gz" -C "/content/"
```

Second cell (input,execute):

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

Third cell (input, execute):

```
model = tf.saved_model.load('/content/ssd_mobilenet_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync_2018_07_03/saved_model')
concrete_func = model.signatures[
tf.saved_model.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY]
concrete_func.inputs[0].set_shape([1, 300, 300, 3])

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_concrete_functions([concrete_func])
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS, tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]

tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open('detect.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

The code below is necessary because there are some ops that are not supported natively by TFLite:

> converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,
> tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS]

but you have to add the specific dependency also at the mobile project following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/ops_select#android_aar).

If you want to shed some MB of the tflite file and make it smaller follow [these procedures](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/model_optimization).

After completion you will see at the left side a detect.tflite model.

Go to [netron.app](http://netron.app) and copy paste the file or browse to upload it. You will see all the details:
[image]

Comment: Trying this, currently getting "TypeError: load() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'tags' and 'export_dir'" from the load() call, think it requires None arg.

Comment: I'm guessing the code is TF2, what would the code be for TF1?

Comment: and kind of need to be able to convert the frozen_graph.pb file, don't have the save_model for my existing trained models

Comment: Sorry just followed what you asked for ...Models from zoo link. If you need something, or you have something specific please tag me.

Comment: The layer names are the ones you see at the image above..if that helps more. And if you have your model uploaded somewhere please tag me to take a look.

Comment: switch to TF2 and was able to convert the saved_model to .tflite file, but this file does not seem to work with tflite

Comment: using tflite example Anroid app get error loading file "E/tflite: Missing 'operators' section in subgraph."

Comment: E/TaskJniUtils: Error getting native address of native library: task_vision_jni
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred when initializing ObjectDetector: Could not build model from the provided pre-loaded flatbuffer: Missing 'operators' section in subgraph.

Comment: so the .tflite it produced does not seem to work with Android

Comment: It is nice that you converted it! Can you upload it to netron.app to verify the input/outputs? NOt every model works with task vision object detector. If netron.app shows correctly input/outputs you can use directly the TFLite interpreter. The example apps do not work out of the box. Check this example on what happens when you have different versions of TF. https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/invalidargumenterror-required-broadcastable-shapes-op-mul/3824/24

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240146/discussion-between-farmaker-and-james).

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def print_layers(graph_def):
    def _imports_graph_def():
        tf.compat.v1.import_graph_def(graph_def, name="")

    wrapped_import = tf.compat.v1.wrap_function(_imports_graph_def, [])
    import_graph = wrapped_import.graph

    print("-" * 50)
    print("Frozen model layers: ")
    layers = [op.name for op in import_graph.get_operations()]
    ops = import_graph.get_operations()
    print(ops[0])
    print("Input layer: ", layers[0])
    print("Output layer: ", layers[-1])
    print("-" * 50)

# Load frozen graph using TensorFlow 1.x functions
with tf.io.gfile.GFile("model.pb", "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()
    loaded = graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

frozen_func = print_layers(graph_def=graph_def)
```

prints the attributes, including the shape, of the input layer, along with the names of input and output layers:

```sh
--------------------------------------------------
Frozen model layers: 
name: "image_tensor"
op: "Placeholder"
attr {
  key: "dtype"
  value {
    type: DT_UINT8
  }
}
attr {
  key: "shape"
  value {
    shape {
      dim {
        size: -1
      }
      dim {
        size: -1
      }
      dim {
        size: -1
      }
      dim {
        size: 3
      }
    }
  }
}

Input layer:  image_tensor
Output layer:  detection_classes
--------------------------------------------------
```

You can then insert correct layer names and shape to your code, and the conversion should work.

Comment: so from your example what would the values of input_shapes input_array be?

Comment: see my above edit with the results of this